# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: object is not defined on checkout page

Tags: magento2, javascript, payment-gateway, checkout-page

`JS object` is not defined on the checkout page.

Already included the script on the checkout page. Exactly the same thing is working on a simple Html page. but creating some issue on magento2.

Comment: Magento2 use requirejs concept (lazy load) so load jquery first then write your jquery code.

Comment: Hello i have included it from  `checkout_index_index.xml` by adding the head like

 `<head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <script src="vendor_::module_/dist/iost.min.js"/>
        <script src="vendor_::module_/dist/test.js"/>
    </head>`

Comment: in your js file load jquery first then write your jquery code

Comment: This is in JAVASCRIPT. The same script and line code is working okay on normal html page

Comment: Yes, but Magento2 use requirejs concept (lazy load) so you should need to load jquery first then write your jquery code.

Comment: require(['jQuery'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Do my stuff here...
    });
});

Comment: Okay, should i remove head from `checkout_index_index.xml` then?

Comment: No, you should need to load jquery first then write your jquery code in your JS file where your JS object is define.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100576/discussion-between-garry-and-sangeeta-chandaliya).

Comment: If I load the written js and the library js scripts to checkout_index_index.xml. then what should I load with requires concept (lazy load) .